# How to iterate json key and value over html in aurelia js

Tags: json, aurelia

I have json as below :

```
 this.myObj = {
        keyOne: 'myValue1',
        keyTwo: 'myValue2',
        keyThree: 'myValue3',
        keyFour: 'myValue4',
    };
```

I want to set key and value in my html.I have tried as below code :

```
 <ul>
 <li repeat.for="prop of myObj | objectKeys">${prop}</li>
 </ul>
```

But my code is not work. Please give me solution regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused about what you wish to accomplish here.
I assume you wish to get the keys of `myObj` and loop through them.
I suggest reading about repeaters at [aurelia documents](http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics#repeaters).

For a solution that may get you going, add this to your modal file:

```
export class ObjectKeysValueConverter {
    toView(value) {
        return Object.keys(value);
    }
}
```

`Object.keys( myObj )` will return an array, which repeat.for attribute requires. It can't iterate objects by default.

Comment: make your link point to repeaters section: http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/basics#repeaters

Comment: Thanks @weagle08, much better resource for it!